# clearing the cache in memory

Tags: particles

In particle settings, we usually want to see updates once we tweak a few things in the 3D viewport, however, the results are cached and hence we don't see the real feedback of the scene:

[image]
Note the "19 frames in memory", which is why if I remove a turbulence force field that was present in the scene, the simulation behaves as if there was one, due to this cache. but, all the buttons seem to be greyed out and nothing is clickable, like the "delete all bakes", which seem to be available only for "**disk cache**". So how do I clear this cache in memory?